# Having ModelBuilder auto-detect work-space environment?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, sql

I have a model that I'm attempting to edit, that is used company wide. We have a structured folder template that all projects conform to. The model takes information from the personal geodatabase and returns a materials list in an excel file.

The tool is for non Arc users, and choosing file path for input and output locations is causing issues.

I need the model to automatically default to whatever database is open, and have it export the excel file to the corresponding folder location for that project.

I've been trying to figure this out on my own and had no luck.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "..whatever database is open..."? An MXD could potentially have many layers loaded, each one from a different workspace.

Comment: Our design projects are done in their own personal geo-databases, so all layers are coming from one location per project. Currently the model has two parameters where the user has to choose: database, and output file location. I'm trying to have the script in the parameters to auto fill absolute path for current work space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe what you are asking is possible with a model. It would certainly be possible with a python script or script toolbox as you can *validate* a parameter, which you can't do with a model.

If the bulk of your workflow is a model then you could use the calculate value tool to pull out the workspace of say the first layer in the MXD but then you would not be able to expose the parameter as you currently have, so it would be a parameter-less model.

You can use this to return a workspace from the first valid layer and use the output of the Calculate Value tool in an inline substitution.

[image: Calculate Value tool]

Python code is:

```py
import arcpy
def getWorkspace():
  mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
  df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]
  lstLayers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "", df)
  ws = None
  for aLyr in lstLayers:
    if aLyr.supports("WORKSPACEPATH"):
      ws = aLyr.workspacePath
      break
  return ws
```

Comment: I feel you are right the more I research. I'm going to try removing the parameter and using the calculate tool. I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: @j.stanfield see edit, this should get you going.

Comment: So wanted to thank you again for the help, but my manager has changed how the tool is to auto-detect database. They've created new MXD template that also has our SDE database, the PERSONAL GDB, and a couple FILE GDB's in it. So now the code needs to reference just the PERSONAL GDB ignoring the rest. I've been looking throught ARCPY and haven't figured it out yet. I thought I'd run it by you?

Comment: I would probably do something like look at the last 3 right characters of the string returned, if it is a personal geodatabase it has to end with "mdb"

Comment: That worked perfectly. Appreciate the help!

Comment: No on the workspacePath string, so in code above if would be `if ws[-3:] == "mdb": do something`.

Comment: The way I got it to work was to use "*Design*" in the (df = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "*Design*", df). The .mdb had (Design) suffixed to every layer I needed. Thank you again for all your help.